# How to log the trace id using Springboot custom filters

Tags: spring-boot, filter, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have few custom filters in my Springboot Webflux API. This project has been activated with Spring Sleuth, however, these filters are not logging the trace and span ids in the log messages.

I made sure that the order was set properly for these filters.

Example:

```
2020-03-23 12:53:18.895 -2020-03-23 12:53:18.895  INFO [my-spring-boot,,,] 9569 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.d.a.f.test.myTestEnvWebFilter      : Reading data from header
```

Can someone please provide your insights on this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. Where did you research and why didn't it help? If it did, what did you do to try to solve this? Currently, we have no idea where you searched and what you tried, so to give a concise answer we'd have to write a tutorial, which is off-topic. Please narrow the problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the default sampler percentage configuration, take a look at this article for an example:

https://www.baeldung.com/tracing-services-with-zipkin